# zeta distribution when s->1

Tags: probability, probability-theory, zeta-functions

Zeta distribution is just a set's density when s->1.

I found this on the Wikipedia page about zeta distribution(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_distribution).

but I can't find a proof for it, can one help me with that?

Comment: Proof of what?.

Comment: Question very unclear.

Comment: I'm sorry. I will make it more clear. It's the theorem under 'The case s = 1' on the Wikipedia Page of zeta distribution, which is lim(s->1+) P(x \in A) = density of A. Thanks a lot.